# The page of the crawl result link does not open

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my Google search result crawl code.

```
class GoogleBotsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'GoogleScrapyBot'
allowed_domains = ['google.com']

start_urls = [
    f'https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+"iphone"+intext:iphone12&hl=en&rlz=&start=0']

def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div//text()').extract()
    links = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
    items = []

    for idx in range(len(titles)):
        item = GoogleScraperItem()
        item['title'] = titles[idx]
        item['link'] = links[idx].lstrip("/url?q=")
        items.append(item)
        df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['title', 'link'])
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1.xlsx')
        writer.save()
    return items
```

I can get nine item results for each title/link.

> [https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+"iphone"+intext:iphone12&hl=en&rlz=&start=0](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+%22iphone%22+intext:iphone12&hl=en&rlz=&start=0)

When I open the excel file (test1.xlsx), all links do not open properly.
[image]
Added as below on "settings.py".

> USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"

> ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pay close attention to the urls that you have extracted, all of them have `sa`, `ved` and `usg` query params. Obviously, these are not part of the target sites urls, but are google search results query params.

To get only the target urls, you should parse the urls using `urllib` library, and extract only the `q` query param.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
target_url = query_params["q"][0]
```

FULL Working code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

class GoogleBotsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'GoogleScrapyBot'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']

    start_urls = [
        f'https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+"iphone"+intext:iphone12&hl=en&rlz=&start=0']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div//text()').extract()
        links = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
        items = []

        for idx in range(len(titles)):
            item = GoogleScraperItem()
            item['title'] = titles[idx]
    
            # Parsing item url
            parsed_url = urlparse(links[idx])
            query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
            item['link'] = query_params["q"][0]

            items.append(item)
            df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['title', 'link'])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1.xlsx')
            writer.save()
        return items
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but need some help. Please review my additional question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203951/scrapy-to-parse-a-url

Comment: thank you. But I have error ,  item['link'] = query_params["url"][0]
KeyError: 'url',  I am sorry bothering.

Comment: could you `print(links[idx])` and post one of the results.

Comment: Here is , links[idx] -> /url?q=https://www.apple.com/my/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwir29KTusHxAhUNP30KHWFnADEQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2hPDue05dbwO0dDn112fBq, however, this link does not open the page. I think it will get only https://www.apple.com/my/iphone/compare/

Comment: try: `item['link'] = query_params["q"][0]` and tell if it works

Comment: Wow, yes, it works which means get valid link per every items. I heartily thank you!!!!